# Error while trying to get fitted values out of auto.arima model (forecast package)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I just started learning about time series and am new to R. I built a simple auto.arima model using the following code.

```
library(forecast)
m1 <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
```

Later, I tried to get the fitted values for the model as follows:

```
fitted(m1)
```

This command throws following error and am not sure what to make of it.

```
Error in eval(object$call$x) - residuals(object) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In fitted.Arima(m1) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.ts") for "-"
```

Can someone please provide an insight?

Comment: If its all the commands you run, it works for me. Try to run it in a clean session of R.

Comment: Thanks...I restarted my R session and it worked like charm...Don't know what went wrong. It's working now.